# Rectangle drawn by google maps DrawingManager does not trigger the mousemove event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to:

- Draw rectangles on a google map
- Have at most on rectangle
- Display the current location of the mouse when it moves

So, I came up with this code - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/vBwf6/4/
I subscribe to the `rectanglecomplete` event of the `DrawingManager` instance in order to dispose of the previous rectangle, save the reference to the new one and subscribe to the mousemove event on the rectangle.

The problem, is that the `mousemove` event is never triggered.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a function, which gives GPS coordinates by pixel offset related to top-left corner of map's container.

```
function getLatLngByOffset( map, offsetX, offsetY ){
    var currentBounds = map.getBounds();
    var topLeftLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( currentBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                                                currentBounds.getSouthWest().lng());
    var point = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint( topLeftLatLng );
    point.x += offsetX / ( 1<<map.getZoom() );
    point.y += offsetY / ( 1<<map.getZoom() );
    return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng( point );
}
```

Add `'onmousemove'` event listener on map's div element, then pass mouse position related to div's top-left corner.

**UPDATE**: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezduA/) (Tested on *Chrome*)