# Google Maps Polygon resize event

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an editable Polygon, just like [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_DrawingTools_deleteAll.html).

I want to "catch" the event when a user is moving the dot around the map (to resize the polygon). I need this functionality to implement snap to point.

Is it possible?

**Edit**

```
this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: true,
    path: this._path
});

var dragging = false;
google.maps.event.addListener(this.polygon, 'mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.vertex) {
        dragging = true;
    }
});
google.maps.event.addListener(this.polygon, 'mousemove', function (event) {
    if (dragging) {
        // dragging
    }
});
google.maps.event.addListener(this.polygon, 'mouseup', function (event) {
    dragging = false;
});
```

The code is working, events are catched. However, i can't access the current dragged point to change it's position.

I also tryied inside `mousemove` event to change the latLng object, but with no effect

**Temporary Solution**

You can't access the Polygon ghost while is resizing, so the only solution to implement the snapping is to do it after the polygon has been resized.

```
this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: true,
    path: this._path
});

var path = this.polygon.getPath();
google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function (event) {
    // Here do the snapping, after the polygon has been resized
});

google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function (event) {
    // Here do the snapping, after the polygon has been resized
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible but not straight forward.

You would need to use a combination of events on the polygon object.

A [PolygonMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent) object has three properties, `edge`, `path` and `vertex`. If the event occured over a `vertex` you will get the index of it otherwise it is undefined.

So if you try the following you may be able to build the functionality you want:

- Listen for the `mousedown` event.  If `vertex` is defined, then `dragging = true`.
- Listen for the `mouseup` event. Set `dragging = false`
- Listen for the `mousemove` event.  If `dragging = true` then get the mouse position. `e.latLng` and do your logic to snap it.

I haven't tried this, but with some tinkering you should get it working using this method.

If `mousemove` doesn't work try using `mouseover`.

If you give it a go and can't get it working, post your code so we can help.

Comment: Thank you! i will give it a try and i will send feedback

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the arguments passed to the `set_at` event handler are `(index, object)`.  The index will correspond to the vertex modified.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from @SeainMalkin with code:

```
var draggingPolygonVertex = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mousedown', function(mdEvent) {
    if(mdEvent.vertex || (mdEvent.vertex == 0)){
        draggingPolygonVertex = true;
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseup', function(muEvent) {
        draggingPolygonVertex = false;
});


google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mousemove', function(mmEvent) {
    if(draggingPolygonVertex){
        // you're now dragging a vertex of the polygon
        // insert snap to grid code
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good approach except that it fails on an editable polygon as editable polygon will show up multiple other vertices that would be added by maps itself and polygon object would not have those vertices inside of its path. Here, I drew three points https://prnt.sc/qkbay8 and Here the other points were added by google maps https://prnt.sc/qkbb76.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem putting together the solution Seain Malkin suggested and the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281039/rectangle-drawn-by-google-maps-drawingmanager-does-not-trigger-the-mousemove-eve) (thanks to both).

Instead of registering a "google event listener" for `mousemove`  to  `polygon` I've registered a DOM event listener to the maps `div` (`useCapture` parameter set to `true`, especially to work with Firefox):

```
map.getDiv().addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (drawing) {
        var latLng = getLatLngByOffset( map, e.clientX, e.clientY );
        // dragging
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is this:

```
path.addListener('bounds_changed', function (event) {
    // Here do the snapping, after the polygon has been resized
});
```

A complete example is here: [Google Doc example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-event?hl=it)