# Serve HTML page and execute its included Javascript in React Native app

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-api-3, react-native-maps

I'm working on a React Native application using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md). Part of this app requires a draggable geofence. Unfortunately, `react-native-maps` does not include this. However, the actual Google Maps Javascript API [does](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-draggable). It even seems possible to allow the user to [resize the polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537549/google-maps-polygon-resize-event), which is my ultimate goal.

Is there a way to serve a static HTML page as part of a React application in a way that would allow seamless navigation between it and the React components **and** correctly execute the Javascript in the static HTML page (see the Google Maps API example linked above)?

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Webview to serve a static HTML. Not sure how well it handles javascript though

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview

Comment: That renders an empty page. It appears the HTML loads, but the script does not execute.